# Descriptive analysis in R

Tags: r

I want to do some descriptive analysis using R for the below data set.I
    tried using melt and dcast function using reshape package but was not able
    to produce desired results.

```
               Age   MARK_Science  MARK_Maths   MARK_IT
               30         98          78          NA
               40         99          NA          91
               26         NA          98          72
               NA         76          99          98
               29         88          NA          69
               26         NA          NA          56
```

I want my output in below format:

```
                                 Age   MARK_Science  MARK_Maths   MARK_IT  
       Mean
       Median
       Total Observation
       Missing Observation
       % Missing Observation
       SD
```

How would I go about producing something like this?
  Can you please guide me with the code with the required format as output?
  Any suggestions?

Comment: Start with ```summary(yourdata)```. Does that show what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks Nancy! But i don`t want to use summary or stat.desc function. Is there any other way as i want my output in above format? Above format looks clear to me and it is easy to compare the results.

Comment: Your data set is a `data.frame` or a `matrix`? You can use `aggregate()` with a selfmade function.

Comment: It`s a data frame. I am not sure if we can use aggregate function when we have all columns as numeric format. I have tried using it but it was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `sapply()`

```
my.agg <- function(x) 
    c(Mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), Median=median(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
    Total.n=length(x), Pct.na=100*sum(is.na(x))/length(x), Sd=sd(x, na.rm=TRUE))
sapply(df, FUN=my.agg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to either melt or reshape, you just need to apply some summary statistics to each column and aggregate the results

```
# example data
set.seed(256)
df <- data.frame(age= rnorm(100, mean= 30, sd= 7),
                 sci= runif(100, 0, 100),
                 math= runif(100, 0, 100),
                 it= runif(100, 0, 100))

# insert missing values
s <- replicate(4, sample(1:100, rpois(1, lambda = 10), replace=F))

for (i in 1:4) {
  df[[i]][s[[i]]] <- NA
}

# tabulate
t <- rbind(apply(df, 2, mean, na.rm=T),
      apply(df, 2, median, na.rm=T),
      apply(df, 2, length),
      apply(df, 2, function(j) sum(is.na(j))),
      apply(df, 2, function(j) sum(is.na(j))) / nrow(df) * 100)

rownames(t) <- c("mean", "median", "n", "n_miss", "pct_miss")
R> t
               age       sci      math        it
mean      30.41222  52.16733  46.58483  49.99577
median    30.84088  51.76666  47.91840  47.42555
n        100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
n_miss    18.00000   9.00000   9.00000  17.00000
pct_miss  18.00000   9.00000   9.00000  17.00000
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. It is very helpful and answers my question. Can you please explain what you did for # insert missing values? I am finding hard to understand the code for # insert missing values.